# IBM Watson assistant issue in Swift

Tags: ibm-watson

I have followed IBM Watson Assistant (swift) tutorial. It was working properly before the iOS12 update. now when i take the build it says 'Reskit.framework is missing'.
I have manually tried to add Restkit.framework but the error still persist.
It worked perfectly on Xcode 9.4 & iOS 11.4.1. The error occurs when builded is taken Xcode10 and deployed in iOS12.

Comment: All of the Watson Swift services have been verified to work in Xcode 10 / iOS 12. My guess is that this is a dependency management issue, so you may need to reinstall the SDK. Are you using Carthage or Cocoapods?

Comment: im using carthage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're building your app with Xcode 10, go to Xcode preferences (Locations tab), and make sure that the Command Line Tools is set to the version of Xcode you are using (Xcode 10.1 if you're on the latest). Then in your project, delete the existing Carthage/ folder and Cartfile.resolved file, and re-run the `carthage update --platform iOS` command.